# C# Windows Forms switching

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I got `Form1`, which creates another form when some button is clicked:

```
 private void ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Form f5 = new Form5();
     f5.Show();
 }
```

When it happens, i need to determine if this form f5 exists,so if it exists,when button is pressed,it simply switches to existing form instead of making new one.If it doesn't exist,then it has to create new form.
How do i do this,if i can't check whether some objects exist or not until i declare them?
How to check f5 existence before i declare it,so i can create it only when there is no such form and it is needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *correct* way of doing this is to maintain a reference to the `Form5` object when you create it. You can do this by, for example, declaring a class-level variable.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private Form5 m_frm5 = null;

    // ...other code...

    private void ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_frm5 == null)
        {
            m_frm5 = new Form5();
        }
        m_frm5.Show();
    }
}
```

Obviously you need to choose a scope appropriately, depending on where you need to access the form object. A `static` local variable might work equally as well, or you might need to make it global for the entire application.

Alternatively, you can iterate through the [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) collection, checking to see if an instance of `Form5` has already been created.

```
private void ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (f.GetType() == typeof(Form5))
        {
            f.Show();
            return;
        }
    }

    Form5 frm5 = new Form5();
    frm5.Show();
}
```

**Pro tip:** Choose more descriptive names for your form class than the defaults. Form5 tells me nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Create `Form5` as a private variable. Before you create a new one, check to see if it exists before creating a new one.

```
 private Form5 form5 = null;

 private void ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(f5 == null || !f5.Visible)
         f5 = new Form5();

     f5.Show();
 }
```

Comment: Unless you can create an instance of Form5 elsewhere in the application in which case you will want to declare this at the application scope, so you will know if it was created somewhere else.

Comment: @Brocco It also depends on whether you want to show the form if it was created elsewhere; you might what to only show the form if it was created at this location in code.

Comment: @Brocco The OP didn't really specify if this form could be created elsewhere. If it can be, then I agree it should be created at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply make the instance part of the parent code:

```
Form f5 = null;

private void ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
if (f5 == null) {
      f5 = new Form5(); 
      f5.Show();
  }
 }
```

**Later edit: You are right, you have captured the correct code sequence :). Mine will open it only once.**

And I'd rather use ShowDialog() if your application is not MDI

Comment: If `f5` is not null, then this method would not do anything. You should be calling `f5.Show()` regardless.